# Installing Python libraries manually on Raspbian

Tags: python, libraries, raspbian

I'm working with reading sensor values through a Raspberry Pi 3 using Python, and I'm currently using this library: https://github.com/szazo/DHT11_Python. I am fairly new to the language and since there are no instructions in the README on how to install this library, I was wondering if anyone knows how to do it manually? I would just like to get rid of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "sensorRead.py", line 4, in <module>
     import dht11
ImportError: No module name 'dht11'
```

So far, I ran these commands:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/szazo/DHT11_Python.git
cd DHT11_Python
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-openssl
```

Then, I moved the library from `/home/pi` to `/usr/lib` but I'm still getting the same error. I must be missing something.

If anyone knows how to properly install this library, then please help! Thank you!

Comment: please mark the answer below as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have your sensorRead.py file in the same folder as dht11.py

Comment: additionally you can get that file with `git clone ...` command

Comment: @user9849588 Hm, then should I just copy the dht11.py file to the same place where sensorRead.py is?

Comment: @Melissa yes, that's the easiest way.